# before_filter not redirecting when using devise and jquerymobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-mobile, devise

When using a format/mimetype called format.mobile and i want to perform an action that requires a user to use sign in first by using the `before_filter :authenticate_user` it does not redirect me to the signin page that devise is suppose to do insted it returns a message in my server log saying `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 336ms` and does not redirect me to the signin page. I am using jquerymobile for my mobile support, how can do the redirect call.

the songs show template

```
<% reply = @song.replies.first(:select => 'id, yes', :conditions => ['user_id = ?', current_user]) %>

<div class="ui-body ui-body-a double-margin-top">
  <p class="small-fonts">
    Show your love or hate for this song.
  </p>
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <%= form_for(:reply, :remote => true, :url => song_replies_path(song)) do |f| %>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :yes, :value => Reply::Response::No %>
                        <div class="ui-block-a">
                          <%= submit_tag "Hate", "data-role"=>"button", "data-icon"=>"trash", "data-theme"=>"b" %>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= form_for(:reply, :remote => true, :url => song_replies_path(song)) do |f| %>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :yes, :value => Reply::Response::Yes %>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                          <%= submit_tag "Love", "data-role"=>"button", "data-icon"=>"love", "data-theme"=>"b" %>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
</fieldset>
</div>


class RepliesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def create
    @reply = Reply.new(params[:reply])
    @reply.song_id = params[:song_id]
    @reply.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.save
        @song = Song.find(params[:song_id])
        format.html { redirect_to @song }
        format.js
        format.mobile {redirect_to @song}
      else
        format.html { redirect_to home_path }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /questions/replies/1
  def update
    @reply = Reply.find(params[:id], :include => :song)
    @song = @reply.song

    was_yes = @reply.yes?
    now_yes = params[:reply][:yes].to_i == Reply::Response::Yes

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.update_attributes(params[:reply])
        # Make sure we keep the question's response cache updated
        if was_yes and not now_yes
          @song.increment(:no_count)
          @song.decrement(:yes_count)
          @song.save
        elsif not was_yes and now_yes
          @song.increment(:yes_count)
          @song.decrement(:no_count)
          @song.save
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @song }
        format.js
        format.mobile { redirect_to @song }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @song }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

the server log

```
Started POST "/songs/12/replies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-21 21:00:56 +0100
  Processing by RepliesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xT1pLXOCmqAf8wuflvesgeUeXuBBpNsfCXf+JMD64rM=", "reply"=>{"yes"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Love", "song_id"=>"12"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 336ms
```

Comment: Without posting some example code, a link to your project or a http://jsfiddle.net it's kinda hard to see the full problem

Comment: just updated the code sample but the problem is from the before filter it does not redirect me to the sign in page. which it is meant to do normally

Comment: i think devise does not authomatically redirect with the mobile format.

Comment: I got the same issue. I'm working on it. Where you able to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, due to the fact that I was using jquery mobile, which uses AJAX calls for the link_to methods. 
In my case, I made it a regular link_to (non-AJAX based) by adding the following to my link

```
data-ajax="false"
```

in the link_to options, i.e:

```
link_to 'Model', {:controller => "models", :action => "any_action"}, "data-ajax" => "false"
```

I hope that helps someone someday.
Cheers! 
Yohann.